# Scala: Implicit resolution, ambigiuty and contravariance

Tags: scala, contravariance, implicits

I have the following piece of Scala with ambigiuous implicits, which I would have thought should work, due to lower priority given to inherited implicits. But it does not - it fails with an `ambiguous implicit values`-error. Can someone explain to me why priorities does not work here?

```
trait Printer[-T] {
  def prettify(instance:T): String
}

trait LowPriorityPrinter {
  implicit val anyPrinter:Printer[Any] = new Printer[Any]{ def prettify(instance:Any) = instance.toString() }
}

object Printer extends LowPriorityPrinter {
  implicit val intPrinter = new Printer[Int]{ def prettify(instance:Int) = instance.toString() }
}

object MyApp extends App {

  def prettyprint[T](i:T)(implicit p:Printer[T]) = println(p.prettify(i))
  prettyprint(234)

}
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/ZE83TvSWpT4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is simple, but nasty. The `LowPriorityPrinter` catch all instance of your type class needs to be generic, not for `Any`:

```
object Printer {
  implicit val intPrinter:    Printer[Int] =
    new Printer[T]{ def prettify(x: T) = x.toString() + " (int") }
  implicit def anyPrinter[T]: Printer[T] =
    new Printer[T]{ def prettify(x: T) = x.toString() + " (general) }
}
```

Basically, the literal `234` is just as much an `Int` as it as an `Any` and neither of those types is more specific than the other (so the priority trick is useless).